# SQL Server help writing this merge command?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which contains a description and an Id. If the Id exists, I'd like to update the description. If not, I'd like to insert a new entry for the Id and description.

I'm trying to do this with a `MERGE` command. Is this the right approach?

If so, any idea why am error occurs in SQL Server Management Studio when I execute my `MERGE`?

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'

Code:

```
MERGE mytbl AS Target
ON (Target.Id = 50)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.Description = 'new description'
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Id, Description)
    VALUES (50, 'new description')
```

Comment: You have a `Target`.  You also need a Source of data. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: [Please read about potential issues with `MERGE`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). I find the traditional `UPDATE ... IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT` methodology much more reliable.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm going to with IF EXISTS... BEGIN..END ... ELSE BEGIN...END.

Answer (score 1):

The source clause is missing. But yes, this is the right approach.

```
MERGE mytbl AS Target
USING(SELECT Id = 50) AS Source
ON Target.Id = Source.Id
```

I don't think there is a simpler approach. The execution plan is perfect, though.

Comment: Alias = (expression) is creeping me out a bit :). I would prefer the ANSI compliant AS.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Source.  You can define Source using a `SELECT` with Id = 50 description = 'new description'.  Then you can use that in the `MERGE`

Try this OTTOMH

```
MERGE mytbl AS Target
Using (Select 50 Id, 'new description' description) Source
ON (Target.Id = Source.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.Description = Source.description
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Id, Description)
    VALUES (Source.Id, Source.Description)
```